# How to fix broken automatic indentation in vim

Tags: vim, code-formatting, indentation, auto-indent

I am trying to use vim 7.2 (on Windows XP) to automatically indent and format some VHDL and Matlab code. To do so I am trying to use the "gg=G" command. However this does not work properly. The code is not properly indented at all.

To give you an example, I had the following source code, which was already properly indented:

```
% This function is based on the code_g_generator() function
function [v_code] = get_code(n_code_number)
% There is no need to clear the persistent variables in this function
mlock 
%% Initialize the internal variables
persistent n_fifo_top;
if isempty(n_fifo_top)
    n_fifo_top = 1;
end

N_MEMORY_SIZE = 4;
if n_code_number > 4
    c_saved_code_fifo = {-1*ones(1, N_MEMORY_SIZE)};
end
```

If I use the "gg=G" command I get:

```
% This function is based on the code_g_generator() function
function [v_code] = get_code(n_code_number)
% There is no need to clear the persistent variables in this function
mlock 
%% Initialize the internal variables
persistent n_fifo_top;
if isempty(n_fifo_top)
        n_fifo_top = 1;
    end

    N_MEMORY_SIZE = 4;
    if n_code_number > 4
        c_saved_code_fifo = {-1*ones(1, N_MEMORY_SIZE)};
    end
```

As you can see, in this example Vim incorrectly indents the code after the first "if" block. For other files I get similar problems (although not necessarily on the first if block).

For VHDL files I get similar problems.

I have tried using different combinations of the autoindent, smartindent and cindent settings. After going through these forums I have also made sure that the "syntax", "filetype", "filetype indent" and "filetype plugin indent" are set to on. Still, it does not work. Also, if I do "set syntax?" I get "matlab" for matlab files and "vhdl" for vhdl files which is correct. And if I do "set indentexpr?" I get "GetMatlabIndent(v:lnum)" for matlab files and "GetVHDLindent()" for vhdl files.

To try to isolate the problem (and ensure that it is not due to one of the vim plugins that I have installed) by doing a fresh install of VIM on a different computer (in which VIM had never been installed before). On that computer I get the same sort of problems (that is why I do not think that I need to give you the .vimrc, but if you need it I can upload it here too).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code#Methods_for_automatic_indentation) wiki page for explanations of the different methods for automatic indentation in vim.

On [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21798-editing-matlab-files-in-vim) page you can find an indent file for matlab which you can use with filetype based indenting. [Here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1450) is a similar one for VHDL.